# Best way to handle connections from multiple instances of an application to a MS Access database?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have an application that connects to a MS Access database. Before you say I should get rid of the Jet Engine, I might do this in the future, in fact what I want my app to do is to be able to select among multiple installed engines. So for now I want my application to be as engine agnostic as possible.

I'm trying to implement a new feature that will let many instances of my application run in the *same machine* and all these instances connect to the same database. But I need to be able to have some control over who access the database each time. I can't just let all instances access it from multiple threads because some queries need to be executed in a row, such as inserting a row and then doing a `@@SELECT IDENTITY` query right away to get the just generated auto identifier.

I don't want the engine to take care of this because all engines are different in this regard. The first thing I thought was using WCF and pipes and write my own little database server that simply wraps around the Jet Engine and the database. Then use `lock`s or `Mutex`es, together with some `RequestExclusiveAccess` and `ReleaseExclusiveAccess` kind of methods to control who can access the database at each moment.

Now I'm thinking using just a `Mutex` and no server should be enough, but I'm still not sure. Is there any other possibility I'm missing here? What do you think would be the most effective way to achieve this?

Comment: Access and simultaneous connections aside, it actually sounds like you want lots of jobs populating a queue of jobs, then a dedicated job actioning whatever is on the queue and notifying callers that their jobs are complete (with results). You can sidestep lots of direct db access by multiple exes then. Knowing what your ultimate goal is here would be useful.

Comment: @dash: Makes sense, but I'm not sure how will I handle data reading here. Sometimes many rows need to be read and I can't just wait for all rows to be read and a data set to be populated, instead I need to use a `DataReader` to read each row. At least this is the way I've been doing it so far.

Comment: This is a web scraping application. It navigates through web pages and stores info in the database. So having multiple instances of my application will increase performance a bit. But note that storing info in the database is not all my app does. It also performs custom user queries on the database. So in a few words, it connects to the database and do with it whatever the user wants to.

Comment: A DataReader wont give you what you want here, really, as it will only start returning rows one at a time when the query has finished executing - it's a good class because it avoids loading lots of data into memory at once like the dataset. Also, your underlying database would need to support dirty reads etc (based on the current state of the table etc) which Access doesn't. Using an RDBMS like SQL Server (or MySql, or...) will mean you can use the transactional and table locking features to achieve a lot of what you want. It will be easier this way.

Comment: However, given that you want to write it yourself, then you are effectively going to need to write a wrapper around a database engine (as suggested) and all the other clients interact with this. You might as well use WCF as any other technology, but you could also achieve this in a single app with queues and a few worker threads which would be a lot less complex.

Comment: @dash: Multiple threads from a single process is not an option. Basically, the `WebBrowser` can only run on the main thread. But that's just basically.

Comment: You don't need to use the WebBrowser for a scrape application; you could have multiple HttpWebRequests, WebClients and then use the HTML Agility Pack. They will all make a GET request to a website and return the response, and, in the case of the HTML Agility Pack, enable you to quite easily parse the response - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I know the HAP. There are many things you can only do with a `WebBrowser` such as running the target's website javascript and messing with all kind of AJAX stuff. This is a _visual_ kind of web scraper so the `WebBrowser` fits nicely. Besides, I'm not going to throw into the trash an application just to rewrite a whole new app that uses the HAP simply because is not too easy to write a database wrapper.

Comment: Ahah - I see - you want to capture the output of a website as if it's been processed by a client. Makes sense. In which case, why not just initialize multiple exe's that ONLY download the websites to an output file in a directory, and your main application can process these in as many batches as you feel like? i.e. only farm out the download to multiple processes, have them save their output to a directory, and your main app can quite simply process this directory then.

Comment: Well that's a variation of the queue suggestion. The thing is that this application is already fully developed. This is just a new feature I'm trying to add. And really the easiest and less intrusive thing to do is to write some kind of wrap around the database. Basically all I need to do is have my old `ExecuteQuery` method, since every data request goes through this method, moved into my wrapper and then I'll only need to change a few lines of code other than writing the server.

Comment: Actually you can look at this application from my profile. Maybe this will all make more sense to you if you do.

Comment: Nice app. Maybe we could go to chat with this later on, but you could probably simplify your approach as above. Given you don't want to change this code, then your comment above is correct; you need to change the implementation of ExecuteNonQuery. You can either communicate between processes using WCF or similar, or have them all read a result table, with only one of your pocesses nominated to process all the other's requests and write the results of these back to that table? Lots of ways :-)

Comment: OK I'll join a chat. I'll be AFK for one of two hours and come back see if you're around.